# Android: Sms Retrieval Api does not get message from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-service, sms-retriever-api

I tried to implement the new Sms retrieval Api in my android application but I could not read the message correctly, my service gets called when a message is received but I cannot get the content of the message from the intent's extras. Here is a sample code from my service:

```
/**
 * BroadcastReceiver to wait for SMS messages. This can be registered either
 * in the AndroidManifest or at runtime.  Should filter Intents on
 * SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.
 */
public class SmsVerificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

        switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // Get SMS message contents
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                Timber.d(message);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Message is: "+ message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                // by sending the code back to your server.
                break;
            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                // Waiting for SMS timed out (5 minutes)
                // Handle the error ...
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Also here is the code sample for how I get the 11 digit token for my application signature,

```
/**
     * This is a helper class to generate your message hash to be included in your SMS message.
     *
     * Without the correct hash, your app won't recieve the message callback. This only needs to be
     * generated once per app and stored. Then you can remove this helper class from your code.
     */
    public class AppSignatureHelper extends ContextWrapper {
        public static final String TAG = AppSignatureHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
    public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
    public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

    public AppSignatureHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

/**
 * Get all the app signatures for the current package
 * @return
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
    ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Get all package signatures for the current package
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        // For each signature create a compatible hash
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null) {
                appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "App code is: " + appCodes.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("App has Key", appCodes.toString());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    return appCodes;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private  String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
    String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
        messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

        // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
        hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
        // encode into Base64
        String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

        Toast.makeText(this, "PKG IS is: " + base64Hash, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
        return base64Hash;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

In the service, this line

```
 String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
```

always return null.

Also, this is the sample of the SMS I sent (less than 140 bytes)

`[#] his this is your code: 1234 APP_11_DIGIT_SIGNATURE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are registering the correct API.

Automatic SMS Verification with the SMS Retriever API require you register as below:

```
// Get an instance of SmsRetrieverClient, used to start listening for a matching
// SMS message.
SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this /* context */);

// Starts SmsRetriever, which waits for ONE matching SMS message until timeout
// (5 minutes). The matching SMS message will be sent via a Broadcast Intent with
// action SmsRetriever#SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.
Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
```

and not:

```
Task<Void> task = client.startSmsUserConsent(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the SMSRetrieve API, only this works

```
 context?.let { it ->
      SmsRetriever.getClient(it).also {
        // We can add user phone number or leave it blank
        it.startSmsUserConsent(null)
          .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "LISTENING_SUCCESS") }
          .addOnFailureListener { Log.d(TAG, "LISTENING_FAILURE") }
      }
    }
```

and not

```
Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
```